# OpenCV works slow in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to work with webcam using C++ and OpenCV in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017, but it works very slow(I can't see any changes in video - only one frame).  Although the same functions work fine in Python. 
 How can I solve this problem? 
 Thanks.

```
Mat frame; 
VideoCapture vid(0);
if (!vid.isOpened())
{
    return -1;
}
else {
    while (vid.read(frame))
    {
        imshow("Video", frame);
        if (waitKey() >= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: To add on to what @Miki said, add your code but make sure its [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Its hard to help you without seeing what you've already done.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you switch from debug to release mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the condition ***waitKey() >= 0.***

Change the code to:

```
Mat frame;
VideoCapture vid(0);
if (!vid.isOpened())
{
    return -1;
}
else {
    while (vid.read(frame))
    {
        imshow("Video", frame);
        int key = waitKey(1);
        if (key == 27)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

waitKey waits the specified time (1) for a key press. In this example we store the value in "key" and if it matches the ascii value 27 (esc key) the program ends.

**Why your code does not work:**

Your program doesn't seem to work because using waitKey() in C++ it is interpreted as waitKey(0) which will wait forever until some key is pressed (0 means infinite waiting). And when a key is pressed the if sentence (>=0) will become true (because the ascii value of the key pressed will be greater or equal than 0), so the program will exit.